# Visual Studio inherits old namespace in a duplicated solution each time I add new cs file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have created a new copy of a .net project following this steps:

1. I have copied the project in a new folder
2. Renamed the solution
3. Renamed the sub folder
4. Edited project file with a text editor and changed the path inside
5. Renamed the namespace

All worked well, the project compiles and I can run it.

The problem is that each time I add a new file to the solution, it inherits the old namespace of the source project...

I have to rename the namespace each time I add a new cs file...

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you edited the properties of the project's default namespace? Properties->Application->Default Namespace for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to pm_2's answer...

I had a project I renamed. (Visual Studio 2017)
Every time I copied an existing .aspx page, the new page and code behind file **would have the old namespace names**. In addition to pm_2's solution I had to make these changes also...

Checking in project file..

> AssemblyInfo.cs:

View Properties Window.`Ctrl+W,P`
Under your project...expand Properties.
AssemblyInfo.cs is here.

Check the name(s) of

> ```
> [assembly: AssemblyTitle("ProjectName")]
> [assembly: AssemblyProduct("ProjectName")]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

In the project properties, there is a default namespace box.  It will use whatever is in this as the default.

[image: default namespace]